# VSlam error while running tutorial.bag

Tags: ros, vslam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I got this error while running vslam-tutorial.bag and of course it can't run

[ INFO] [1298885315.414216976]: Opening vslam_tutorial.bag

Waiting 0.2 seconds after advertising topics... done.

Hit space to toggle paused, or 's' to step.

Client [/wide_stereo/stereo_vslam_node] wants topic /wide_stereo/right/camera_info to have datatype/md5sum [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo/c9a58c1b0b154e0e6da7578cb991d214], but our version has [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo/1b5cf7f984c229b6141ceb3a955aa18f]. Dropping connection.

Client [/wide_stereo/stereo_vslam_node] wants topic /wide_stereo/left/camera_info to have datatype/md5sum [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo/c9a58c1b0b154e0e6da7578cb991d214], but our version has [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo/1b5cf7f984c229b6141ceb3a955aa18f]. Dropping connection.

How can I solve this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9227/vslam-error-while-running-tutorial.bag/) by [Tien Thanh](https://answers.ros.org/users/135/tien-thanh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2011-02-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Homer Manalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/74/homer-manalo/) on 2011-03-02**:
Ooops, now I can also see this error on my system! This works in cturtle (actually not fully cause I still have some problems (http://answers.ros.org/question/112/vslam-tutorial) but not on recently installed diamondback (just updated to final release).

**Comment by [Tien Thanh](https://answers.ros.org/users/135/tien-thanh/) on 2011-02-28**:
Yes, it still have the same error

**Comment by [Homer Manalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/74/homer-manalo/) on 2011-02-27**:
Can you download the bag again and see if it is still the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just copy and paste answer from Homer, Thanks!

Ooops, now I can also see this error on my system! This works in cturtle (actually not fully cause I still have some problems (http://answers.ros.org/question/112/vslam-tutorial) but not on recently installed diamondback (just updated to final release). - Homer Manalo (19 hours ago)

---

Originally posted by [Tien Thanh](https://answers.ros.org/users/135/tien-thanh/) with karma: 231 on 2011-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's a normal printed text at the console, just wait for the video to start, it it's slow and takes time, mine does.

---

Originally posted by [Homer Manalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/74/homer-manalo/) with karma: 475 on 2011-02-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a duplicate of [this problem](http://answers.ros.org/question/327/vslam-tutorial-camerainfo-error) and [answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/327/vslam-tutorial-camerainfo-error?answer=830#830).

---

Originally posted by [rreid](https://answers.ros.org/users/323/rreid/) with karma: 124 on 2011-03-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2